# Internal storage not mounting on all Android M ROMs

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, internal-storage, rom-flashing, mount, internal-sd

I have a problem with my HTC Desire 816G (MT6592). Whenever I install the Android M ROM, internal storage doesn't mount. My phone's internal storage doesn't appear in USB mode and nor in file manager. The phone's features like Gallery, Camera, Recording, etc., are not working *on all Marshmallow ROMs*. Lollipop and Kit Kat work fine. I didn't have this problem with Marshmallow ROMs before. I've been stuck for around 2 weeks now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to format internal storage with /system, /data, /cache. Do these format with recovery, whatever you are using.

Do it multiple times until all of them get mounted and internal storage shows your space.

<sub>Two days before on my new rom flashing I got hell out of that situation by doing so as written above.</sub>

Comment: tried it, didn't work :(